# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo programación básica en Java y al intentar recorrer un `array` unidimensional me sale este error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>         at Array_2.main(Array_2.java:6)
> ```

Y realmente no se que puedo hacer para solucionarlo, este es el código:

```
public class Array_2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int t = 0;
        int numeros[] = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            numeros[i] = i + 10;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
            System.out.println(numeros[t]);
            t++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1ro, que no es `<= 5` si no `< 5`.

2do, en el segundo for ya tienes declarado `j`, entonces para que utilizas `t`.

Te dejo el codigo:

```
public class Array_2{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int numeros[] = new int[5];

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            numeros[i] = i + 10;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.println(numeros[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Si realizas una prueba de escritorio te daras cuenta que cuando `i` sea igual a 5, la condicion del for se cumple, por lo que entra a ejecutar el cuerpo o bloque del for, y cuando se trate de acceder a la posicion 5 del array arrojara una excepcion indicando que ese indice (`i` o `j`) esta fuera de los limites del array.

¿Y... por que esto? Pues por que estas declarando un array de 5 posiciones, pero se empienza a contar desde la posicion cero, y de cero a cuatro ya estan las cinco posiciones.

Answer (score 1):

hay que recordar que los arreglos comienzan desde el índice `0`, entonces si tienes uno de tamaño `[5]` pues su primer índice es `0` y el último es `4`, por lo tanto no está bien declarado tu `for`, ya que le estas diciendo que termine en el índice `5`: `(i<=5 ó j<=5)` cuando debería ser en el `4`, de dos formas:

```
i <= 4
```

ó

```
i < 5
```

Saludos.

Comment: se te fue el índice, aunque tu respuesta en todo lo demás es correcta, hice la edición y además dejé formato de código en las partes que corresponde. Te invito a darle clic en _editar_ a tu respuesta para que veas como se hace. Un saludo.